# Why can relaxed operation be reordered? Doesn't program order imply happens-before?

Tags: c++, atomic, memory-barriers, stdatomic, memory-model

In the book *C++ Concurrency in Action*, when introducing relaxed ordering, the author says:

> Relaxed operations on different variables can be freely reordered provided they obey any happens-before relationships they’re bound by

but in this [page on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order), it gives an example about relaxed ordering

```
// Thread 1:
r1 = y.load(std::memory_order_relaxed); // A
x.store(r1, std::memory_order_relaxed); // B
// Thread 2:
r2 = x.load(std::memory_order_relaxed); // C 
y.store(42, std::memory_order_relaxed); // D
```

> is allowed to produce r1 == r2 == 42 because, although A is sequenced-before B within thread 1 and C is sequenced before D within thread 2, nothing prevents D from appearing before A in the modification order of y, and B from appearing before C in the modification order of x. The side-effect of D on y could be visible to the load A in thread 1 while the side effect of B on x could be visible to the load C in thread 2. In particular, this may occur if D is completed before C in thread 2, either due to compiler reordering or at runtime.

My question is: C is sequenced-before D in thread2 thus C is also happens-before D, right?

Does the reordering of operation D and C contradict with what says in the book, that relaxed operations can be reordered but must obey happens-before relationships? In what conditions can relaxed operations be reordered?

Comment: There is no global ordering of events. Just because the load in the thread _happens-before_ the store to the other atomic, doesn't mean that all threads need to agree that the store to the former occurred before the store to the latter and because there is no rule establishing such an order, the compiler or CPU is free to reorder the instructions (in terms of real time ordering). I feel like this has been asked about this example multiple times, let me try to find a duplicate to link to.

Comment: @user17732522 I've seen some other questions about this example, but still can't understand why it can be reordered....but isn't the reorder of C and D breaks the happens-before relationships between them? if they can be reordered, do I misunderstand what the book says?

Comment: `A` _happens-before_ `B` and `C` _happens-before_ `D`, but that's it. There is no _happens-before_ relation between any other pair of these evaluations. But the _happens-before_ relation between `C` and `D` doesn't have any practical effect, because neither of the two evaluations depend on the other. The only guarantee that _happens-before_ makes is that a value computation of a scalar in the latter evaluation will observe a value stored by the former evaluation (assuming there is no other store to the scalar which happens inbetween the two).

Comment: But `C` and `D` operate on different variables, so practically the _happens-before_ relation has no impact. The compiler is allowed to perform any transformation of the program which doesn't affect the observable behavior and the order of the instructions `C` and `D` doesn't affect the possible observable behaviors of the program because the happens-before (or sequenced-before) relation imposes no restrictions on the observable behavior. Like `x = 1; std::cout << y;` in a single-threaded program the compiler is free to reorder the statements because they don't depend on one another.

Comment: What the book means with "_obey_" is that the requirements imposed on the observable behavior of the program due to happens-before relations should not be affected by the transformation. That is kind of a weird point to make though, because the statement is true even if you drop "_due to happens-before relations_". The book does not mean that the _happens-before_ relation must be the same after the reordering. The reordering changes `C` happens-before `D` to `D` happens-before `C`, but that is ok, because the happens-before relation between the two has no impact on observable behavior.

Comment: @user17732522 thx! but if we are using sequentially-consistent ordering, even if C and D operate on different obejct, these two still can't be reordered, is that right?

Comment: Yes, sequential consistency imposes an _additional_ restriction on the observable behavior that all atomic access with seq_cst (no matter which atomic) have a global total order in such a way that it is compatible with the _sequenced-before_ (but not necessarily the _happens-before_) relations between these accesses in the threads.

Comment: I don't think they can be reordered under any common sense interpretation. There is no reasonable C/C++ semantics that allows reordering or anything surprising. That's because C/C++ std committees never tried to make a real thread semantic like Java, because it's too complicated. And it's even more complicated in C/C++ because UB exists, unlike Java like languages. We have no std and are left with feelings and trying to understand what compiler writers think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common misunderstanding.  It is true that load C *happens before* store D.  That is **not** saying that C has to actually be *executed*, or become visible, before D.

At the end of the day, the only relevance of the happens-before relation, or any other element of the memory model, is what it tells you about what your program will actually do (its observable behavior).  And that is ultimately dictated by what values are returned by your loads.  The happens-before relation provides such information in three ways:

- the coherence rules explained on the page you link (write-write, read-write and so on),
- in telling you whether or not you have a data race
- via the "visible side effect" rule.  (cppreference misstates that rule: it phrases it in terms of modification order, but it is meant to apply to non-atomic variables which in C++20 do not have a modification order.)

All of those rules are ultimately based on knowing whether or not you have a happens-before relationship between two reads or writes **of the same variable**.

So since C and D are accesses to *different* variables, the only reason that we would care whether one *happens before* the other is if we can use that fact as part of a longer chain of reasoning, to eventually deduce a happens-before (or a "does not happen before") between two accesses to the *same* variable.  In the program at hand, we have no way to do that.  The statement that C happens before D is true but completely useless, and so it does not in any way restrict the compiler / machine from reordering how C and D are actually executed or made visible.

In understanding relations such as *happens before*, *dependency-ordered before*, etc, it is best to be guided by the actual formal definitions, and not by your intuition about what their names seem to imply.  The names are just names.

Comment: The "two accesses to the same variable" you're talking about which make this interesting would normally be accesses from different threads.  e.g. store to a buffer, then release-store a "ready" flag.  If an an acquire-load sees ready == true, then its reads from the buffer happen *after* the stores in the other thread. (https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/). I think if I didn't already know how synchronizes-with worked, I'd find that description unclear, since my first thought was about one thread making multiple accesses to a variable.  But yes it's a good point